# Still receiving online messages/notifications after disabling cellular data

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

When disabling 3G/network usage (go to Settings->Cellular->Use cellular data for:) for a specific application (eg. Facebook, Hangouts, Messenger, ...) I can still receive messages and/or notifications on my iPhone.

Is this some kind of bug in iOS [version: 7.1(11D167) - modemfirmware: 2.18.02]?

Comment: I guess you're not connected to a Wifi or so, right?

Comment: No I'm sure I'm only connected to 3G

Comment: After changing the setting restart the phone so the network provider gets it.

Comment: Are you serious @Buscar웃 ?

Comment: If you turn off cellular data only for Facebook messenger will still send you notifications and vice versa. I can't imagine an other possible scenario.